# Json decode is not working?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Actually I want convert json array to string for that I used json_decode but it is returning nothing How to solve this?

Below is my array,

```
[{"Product":"Fantasy Brown","productimage":"images/fantasy-brown.jpg"},{"Product":"Bruno White","productimage":"images/bruno-white.jpg"},{"Product":"Barcunda Black","productimage":"images/barcunda-black.jpg"},{"Product":"Iceberg","productimage":"images/iceberg.jpg"},{"Product":"Mercury White","productimage":"images/mercury-white.jpg"},{"Product":"Desert Brown","productimage":"images/desert-brown.jpg"},{"Product":"Blue Venatino","productimage":"images/blue-venatino-marble.jpg"}]
```

the above array should be converted to string and also I want display product and productimage  in string format from that array.

Below is my code,

```
$cart_items = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('cart'));</script>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart_items);
die;
$details = json_decode($cart_items);
// $x = $cart_items[];
echo $details;die;
```

Comment: `json_decode` provide array. so you can't `echo` it .use `print_r()`

Comment: `$cart_items` as defined above is not json, why die befoe json_decode

Comment: @anant I have changed to print_r but it is not printing anything.

Comment: The code doesn't make sense to me. The variable `$cart_items` is only a javascript string, not a JSON nor an array.

Comment: @koala Yeung Data is coming from local storage.

Comment: Your code is wrong, $cart_items holding a html/string ( with script tag ) not json string.

Comment: @Mohan: You cannot get browser content like this in PHP. PHP only gets what on the server. Write an AJAX endpoint and have a local javascript submit the `localStorage` value to it.

Comment: You can't execute JS in PHP. PHP is executed on the server. Any JS you have in variables, will just be a normal string, nothing else. When PHP is done with all it's execution, it will be sent to the browser, which parse any HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: The data will be in local storage and when I Print that array it is printing like below, [{"Product":"Fantasy Brown","productimage":"images/fantasy-brown.jpg"},{"Product":"Bruno White","productimage":"images/bruno-white.jpg"},{"Product":"Barcunda Black","productimage":"images/barcunda-black.jpg"},{"Product":"Iceberg","productimage":"images/iceberg.jpg"},{"Product":"Mercury White","productimage":"images/mercury-white.jpg"},{"Product":"Desert Brown","productimage":"images/desert-brown.jpg"},{"Product":"Blue Venatino","productimage":"images/blue-venatino-marble.jpg"}].

Answer (score 1):

You code wouldn't work. You're mixing client side and server side programming in a wrong way.

From the server point of view, `$cart_items` is only a string containing:

```
<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('cart'));</script>
```

Nothing more.

It is your browser that parse the server output, i.e. the Javascript, to the JSON string. Since the conversion only happens on browser side, the server side (i.e. your PHP script) doesn't get it.

You need to reconsider your code logic. Maybe you need to have javascript that submit the localStorage content to server. Or maybe have your problem solved only with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you all need to set json_decode() 'true' i.e

```
$details = json_decode($cart_items,true);
```